# Filebeat is not collecting logs from pods annotated with co.elastic.logs/enabled: "true"

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I am trying to setup ELK stack on kubernetes. To collect logs from our pods I am setting hints based autodiscover for filebeat, and then annotating the pods with `co.elastic.logs/enabled: "true"` as per the docs. I can see the pods are annotated and it is generating logs. But those logs are not collected by filebeat. Here are my configurations so far.

```
# Setup Logstash.
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: logstash.k8s.elastic.co/v1alpha1
kind: Logstash
metadata:
  name: jaegerpoc-elastic
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRefs:
    - name: jaegerpoc-elastic
      clusterName: jes
  version: 8.9.1
  pipelines:
    - pipeline.id: main
      config.string: |
        input {
          beats {
            port => 5044
          }
        }
        output {
          elasticsearch {
            hosts => "http://jaegerpoc-elastic-es-http.elastic-system.svc:9200"
            user => "${JES_ES_USER}"
            password => "${JES_ES_PASSWORD}"
            index => "logs"
          }
        }
  services:
    - name: beats
      service:
        spec:
          type: ClusterIP
          ports:
            - port: 5044
              name: "filebeat"
              protocol: TCP
              targetPort: 5044
EOF
```

```
# Setup FileBeat
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: jaegerpoc-elastic
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 8.9.1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: jaegerpoc-elastic
  config:
    filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          node: "minikube"
          hints:
            enabled: true
            default_config:
              enabled: false
              type: container
              paths:
                - "/var/log/containers/*\${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log"
    output.elasticsearch:
      enabled: false
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["jaegerpoc-elastic-ls-beats.elastic-system.svc.cluster.local:5044"]
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        serviceAccountName: jaegerpoc-elastic-beat-sa
        automountServiceAccountToken : true
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        containers:
        - name: filebeat
          volumeMounts:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            mountPath: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
        volumes:
        - name: varlogcontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
        - name: varlogpods
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/pods
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
EOF
```

Now instead of autodiscover if I setup filebeat with inputs configuration of type container, I can see logs from all the pods.

```
filebeat.inputs:
    - type: container
      paths:
      - /var/log/containers/*.log
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I' not sure you should have a backslash in the container log path: `/var/log/containers/*\${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log` ([see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat-configuration.html#k8s-beat-role-based-access-control-for-beats))

Comment: Tha backslash is to escape the `$` sign since the configs are not in a separate yaml file but instead embedded in the bash script. I have also confirmed this not to be the issue by separating out the yaml config. @Val

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this format.

```
   filebeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          in_cluster: true
          node: "${NODE_NAME}"
          hints.enabled: true
          hints.default_config:
            type: container
            paths:
              - /var/log/pods/*/*.log
    
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ["logstash-host:5044"]
```

If it doesn't work, try this one as follows.

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      in_cluster: true
      node: "${NODE_NAME}"
      templates:
        - condition:
            equals:
              kubernetes.labels.app: "nginx"
          config:
            - type: container
              paths:
                - /var/log/pods/*/*.log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash-host:5044"]
```

Let's see what happens.

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html